# Check whether two functions are equal

Tags: functions

How can I check wether two function in Mathematica are equal?

I mean functions like `f[x_]=x` and `g[x_]=x-1+1`.

Thank you.

Comment: In this case, `f[x] == g[x]`. For more complicated functions you might need `f[x] == g[x]//Simplify`, `f[x] == g[x]//FullSimplify`, or transformations (e.g., `ExpToTrig`, `TrigToExp`) of one or the other functions in addition to simplification.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4):

There are some nice features built in, see:

[Testing Expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TestingExpressions.html)

[TrueQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrueQ.html)

[SameQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html)

```
f[x_] := x
g[x_] := x - 1 + 1

TrueQ[f[x] == g[x]]
```

> `True`

```
Simplify[f[x] == g[x]]
```

> `True`

```
f[x] === g[x]
```

> `True`